# Error "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'"

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I have the below T SQL statement but keep getting the error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'

Where am I going wrong?

```
DECLARE @NSQL2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SOURCETABLE NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT TOP 1 @SOURCETABLE = TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'IN_PRODUCT________________%' 
  AND TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'

SET @NSQL2 = 'UPDATE [' + @SOURCETABLE + '] SET OnSale = '''+ CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),OnSale, 112)+'''

EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @NSQL2
```

Comment: The single-quote string is '''', that is, 4 single quotes. But instead, you have only used three in the final part of SET @NSQL2

Comment: As-is, your statements can't work, escaping or no. Where's the column `OnSale` supposed to be coming from? Are you trying to change columns to a new type? That'll require a bit more effort than just sticking in a `CONVERT`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    SET @NSQL2 = 'UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(@SOURCETABLE) 
                 + ' SET OnSale = CONVERT(nvarchar(10),OnSale, 112)'
```

Comment: May not give a syntax error, but what is this supposed to achieve?

Comment: Update some table with column OnSale = CONVERT(nvarchar(10),OnSale, 112). Why does author want it? who knows

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work using the below:

```
SET @NSQL = 'UPDATE [' + @SOURCETABLE + '] SET OnSale =  CONVERT(nvarchar,CAST(OnSale AS DATETIME), 120)'
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you intend for the Convert statement to be part of your string as a literal?

```
SET @NSQL2 = 'UPDATE [' + @SOURCETABLE + '] SET OnSale = CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),OnSale, 112)'
```